# Are there any cinematics that depict gnomes?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So Blizzard just showed the Legion cinematic introduction, and gnomophiles are again upset that no gnomes are shown. Apparently, this has been happening in every cinematic released for World of Warcraft. In fact, the only cinematic I can think of that shows a gnome is the promotional video for the level 90 upgrade you can buy. As far as I know, all other playable races have been shown in cinematics, but gnomes haven't made any appearance yet.

I only play Horde and only PvE, so maybe there's some cinematic during PvP or in the Alliance campaign that shows a gnome. I'm not sure though. Is there any cinematic in any of the expansions, whether it be prerendered, using the ingame engine or actually recorded, that shows a gnome? I know there are several quest-related events that show things from your perspective involving a gnome (like the entire Gnomeregan eventline), but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: Come on, you can't honestly tell me you've never wanted to play a [pink-haired female gnome mage](http://i.imgur.com/JTI2f.jpg)! As for cinematics, I can't recall any offhand with gnomes...

Comment: @MichaelHampton If I played on Alliance, I would probably try and make as many of my characters gnomes. Horde for life though (Lok'Tar Ogar!)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can remember there are no cinematics that have a gnome protagonist. If you're looking for any kind of gnome presence though, there is a single cinematic that comes to my mind that may satisfy you:

[The Wrathgate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ch4rc5W4dKY)

See? There's your gnome, a pink-haired one even, shown for ***three whole seconds***. In the background. While Bolvar Fordragon passes in front of the frame. ([starting at second 21](https://youtu.be/Ch4rc5W4dKY?t=21s))